# How App Engine application can get a list of instance developers

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How Google App instance can get the list of developers (like in Administration > Developers).

Hard-coding developer's email is a bad idea because nothing lasts forever.

I would like to get a solution in python (because I don't know java).

Comment: Short of having your app login to the admin dashboard and screenscaping, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: I agree with Wooble. Some sort of loathsome screen-scraping is the only way that this would be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this programmatically, currently. If you only need to email all the admins, however, you can use [send_mail_to_admins](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/functions.html).

Comment: Thank you. I knew about "send_mail_to_admins(sender, subject, body, **kw)", but what should I do with 'sender'?  If is not in developers I'm getting "Unauthorized sender Traceback". How can I not use 'sender' at all (or get it from App Engine instance)?

Comment: You need to specify sender in a configuration file somewhere, or get it from the logged in user, unfortunately.